# Tensorflow SavedModel and variable batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to export my object detection model and have a variable batch size in the inference mode. Usually, a default size is 1, but in my case more a flexible batch is needed.
Thus, my first question - is it even possible to have a variable batch size in a saved model?
Certainly, it's possible to set a fixed batch size greater than 1, but then I can't do inferences on smaller batches.
Error for the batch size fixed to 10 and a real batch of size 8:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Trying to access element 8 in a list with 8 elements.
     [[{{node map/while/body/_1/TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem}}]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Trying to access element 8 in a list with 8 elements.
     [[{{node map/while/body/_1/TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem}}]]
     [[generate_detections/combined_non_max_suppression/CombinedNonMaxSuppression/_82]]
```

Does it mean only `combined_non_max_suppression` is a problem?

EDIT:
Basically, I use [Tensorflow Mask RCNN TPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/models/official/mask_rcnn). The above error comes probably from the [postprocessing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/official/mask_rcnn/postprocess_ops.py#L266).
I export the model with:

```
python official/mask_rcnn/export_saved_model.py \
    --use_tpu=False \
    --output_normalized_coordinates=False \
    --input_type='image_tensor' \
    --batch_size=10 \
```

then do test inferences with:

```
predict_fn = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_dir, tags=['serve']).signatures['serving_default']
result = predict_fn(images)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. please add your code to the question so we could look at it.

Comment: Sure! I've added assemble, export and inference code.